# Max limit post Magento x AWS

Tags: magento

I have more than a thousand customer registrations and when starting a total CSV export process it does not execute. It just does not happen.
I use Magento.

Note: For selection of 200 entries I can do the export ... the problem is in total accomplishment.

Note II: An expert in Magento requests that the Max Limit post from the server be increased.

How can I change the setting for Max Limit Post?